# How to solve the following recursive equation using $\mathcal{Z}-$transform?

Tags: z-transform

Consider the following

$$
T(n) = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{for } n=1\\
2T(n/2) + n, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

This can be solved via recursion tree or backwards substitution as follows

$$
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n \\
= 2(2T(n/4)+\frac{n}{2})+n\\
= 4(2T(n/8)+\frac{n}{4})+2n\\
...\\
=2^kT(n/2^k)+kn
$$
For the base case, $k=\log_2(n)$

So,
$$
T(n)=n\log_2(n)
$$

But I want to solve this using $\mathcal{Z}-$transform or any other more suitable transform it it exists. This is how much I have done

$$
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n \\
\mathcal{Z}\{T(n)\} = 2\mathcal{Z}\{T(n/2)\} + \mathcal{Z}\{n\}\\
T(z) = 2T(z^2)+\frac{z}{(z-1)^2}
$$

$T(z^2)$ and $T(z)$ both are functions of $T(z)$. We can also say them to be $T(z^2)$.
I am stuck here

How to proceed after this? Should I take $T(z)-2T(z^2)$ just as $cT(z^2)$ and proceed? Or should I do something else?

Comment: Clarification requested: what does $T(3)$ equal?

Comment: @user2661923 Please take the floor

Comment: Thanks.  You may wish to edit your posting.  Normally, the *floor* function is represented by (for example) $$T(n) = 2T\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor + n.$$  I *mathjax* typeset this via `$$T(n) = 2T\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor + n.$$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First making $n = 2^m$ and then considering

$$
T(2^m) = 2T(2^{m-1})+2^m
$$

as

$$
R(m) = 2R(m-1) + 2^m
$$

Now you can solve $R(m)$ by using the $\mathcal{Z}$ transform, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cesareo